# If statement not giving desired result

Tags: java, if-statement

I have created a `Hostel` class and a `Room` class, the `Hostel` class contains an ArrayList `rooms`, one value in this  Arraylist is the Boolean `available`. In the `Hostel`class i have created an if statement which is supposed to show any entry in the ArrayList where boolean `available` is true but instead it shows all values including those where `available` was false, but has now been changed to true. can anyone tell me where i have gone wrong.

```
public Room showAvail()
{
    String theString = "Available Rooms";

    if (Room.available == true)

    for (Room room : rooms)
    {
           theString = theString + room.getRoomData() + "\n";
           System.out.println(theString);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should use `void` instead of `Room` as a return type.

Comment: Why available is a static variable? What is rooms variable which is used in the loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- It seems that you've declared the variable `Room.available` as a static variable, thus as part of the class, not of the rooms. All rooms will share the same available status.
- The if statement is outside the loop, thus either the loop is executed for all rooms or for no rooms at all
- You declare to return a Room, but then you always return null. Either return void or return a `List<Room>` for the available rooms.
- You don't need to test `if (variable == true)`, since `if (variable)` will do the same, although it won't do any arm. (style)
- Use curly braces and indentation for the if statement, for added clarity. (style)

Here is a code fragment. I don't know whether `theString` will get all rooms or only those available, in the second case move it inside the if braces.

```
for (Room room : rooms)
{
       theString = theString + room.getRoomData() + "\n";
       if (room.available) {
           System.out.println(theString);
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have taken on all you have said and this works as i hoped

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement is out of place.  Try putting it inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather hard to answer this since you have not shown the class declarations.

It sounds as though your `if` statement needs to be inside the for loop:

```
for (Room room : rooms)
{
     if (room.available)
     {
         theString = theString + room.getRoomData() + "\n";
         System.out.println(theString);
     }
}
```

For this to work the `available` field would need to be an instance variable rather than a static variable and that is probably the crux of your problem.